# How to get online status of facebook user?

Tags: node.js, facebook, sockets, oauth

I wanna to understand how I can retrieve the online status of a Facebook user. For example, I'm logged in my application through JWT auth, and then in my settings page, I wanna to see my facebook online status.

Do I need to log in through OAuth, or just I can put on the field my facebook userID and then make a request to facebook API?

Also if it's possible to have socket connection with that online status to know in real time my status?

Maybe do you know cases with node.js and socket.io with it?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a user’s “online status”.

> Do I need to log in through OAuth, or just I can put on the field my facebook userID and then make a request to facebook API?

Even if you did make an API request with a valid user token, that says little about the user’s online status.

The token stays valid for two hours (for a short-lived one), but the user isn’t necessarily online “on Facebook” for the whole time. Only if they logged out of your app explicitly, thereby invalidating the token, you could take the error message you would then get on the next attempt to make an API request using that expired token as an indicator. But then they would also have to login to your app again, before you could recognize them as “online” again.

Comment: So, I'm can't track on my app if user is online / offline on facebook?

Comment: No, you can’t. Would be a pretty big invasion of privacy. What they do outside of your app, isn’t “your business.”

Comment: Interesting, I thought like if I logged in through OAuth I can see any info of user, but yes I can't track if I'm online / offline on Facebook

Comment: any info of a user? yeah, that would definitely be a big privacy issue. you can only get the info a user specifically authorized. and you can only detect if a user is online on YOUR website, but not on facebook.